# Minecraft pocket edition asks for additional payment

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently deleted Minecraft: Pocket Edition in my apple device.

When I wanted to re-download it, it said that I needed to pay again, even though I had already purchased it. I tried logging out of my account, and logging back in again, but that didn't make it work.

How do I re-download Minecraft: Pocket Edition, without paying for it again, on the same account?

Comment: Check your receipts, also, you should get an email when you make a purchase, if you do there's a link called "there was a problem" or something like that. You can get a refund with that and then repurchase. Alternatively, you could contact Apple about it. Rumor has it they have excellent customer service and will do everything to make it right

Answer (score 9):

This is a quirk that you sometimes get on the App Store. Usually, you can just press buy again, and after you enter your password, it tells you something like:

> You have already brought this product and will not be charged again.

However, if you don't want to risk it, you can either: check the "Purchased" tab, anything you download of the Purchased tab should be free, as you own it, or, you could download your purchases onto iTunes, and then sync them on to your device.

Comment: I tried going to the purchase tab but all I saw was 7 other games that I previously bought but no minecraft in there.

Comment: Did you try the other methods?

Comment: I don't really want to risk it...

Answer (score -5):

I had to shut down / turn on the second device to make Minecraft appear as 'Purchased' in 'My Apps' -> Google Play, before it was asking me to pay again while logged in with the same account and while showing the game in my account order history.

Comment: The tag says ios and you write about *Google Play*. This does not provide an answer

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355, the answer is in fact for Google Play, but the problem OP is encountering is not specific to the platform. As such, having a Google Play solution is productive to the users that play on android.